# Match with capturing groups inside of lookaheads

Tags: regex, grafana, grafana-variable

I have following texts:

```
elasticsearch_sync_queue_lowerlevelgiberish_ManualAllocationPolicy:pending
elasticsearch_sync_queue_SynchronizationProcessor:processing
```

I'd like to extract `text` and `value` like:

```
text=ManualAllocationPolicy 
value=elasticsearch_sync_queue_lowerlevelgiberish_ManualAllocationPolicy
text=SynchronizationProcessor
value=elasticsearch_sync_queue_SynchronizationProcessor
```

I've used this expression but I'm not able to remove the text `:*`.

```
^(?=.*?(?<text>[A-Z][^:]*))(?<value>[^:]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/lGhrPu/1

**EDIT:** This is being used in a Grafana variable, so the result of query might be little bit different.

Comment: Maybe I did not understand correctly but I think you just need to change the Regex101 "function" to **List** (print using vars) instead of **Substitution** (replace in original string).

Comment: Maybe `^(?<text>[^:\n]*?_(?<value>[^:_]+)):`? See https://regex101.com/r/lGhrPu/2

Comment: @AymDev no no I don't need list. If you look into substitution it still produces `:processing` at the end. I'm using this in grafana and it doesn't produce the output with given expression. So something is probably wrong even there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your capturing groups are working fine. You should either be using the **List** function on **Regex101**, or complete the expression to include the missing parts by adding `:.*$` at the end:

```
^(?=.*?(?<text>[A-Z][^:]*))(?<value>[^:]+):.*$
```

**Substitution** is used to replace in a string, leaving the unmatching part in the output.

Comment: you've led me to correct solution `^(?=.*?(?<text>[A-Z][^:]*))(?<value>.+)(:.*)`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one `(?<value>.*_(?<text>[^:_]*)):`

https://regex101.com/r/JpCAva/1

The idea is to utilize the last `_` separator by specifying it between the groups (or in this case inside the value group)